# Trouble updating one to many relationship (trying to learn by doing)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

***Using Razor Pages.***

So I'm trying to get a one to many relationship to update without success. The primary entity will update fine on its edit page, but I try to update the dependent entity, it does not update and the page just returns.

**Employee Model**

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
        //________________________
        // Relationships
        public ICollection<EmployeeAddress> EmployeeAddresses { get; set; }
    }
```

**EmployeeAddress Model**

```
public class EmployeeAddress
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }

        //______________________________
        // Relationship
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }
```

On the index page, I can show all the properties of the Employee model and EmployeeAddress model.

I have a button to take me to an edit page for Employee and a button to take me to a page to edit the address. I can successfully edit the Employee and return to the index page, but when I try to update the address, it just returns to the index page.

Not sure what I need to do or include to get that to work. Below are the Pages and underlying cs classes.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@page "{id:int}"
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index- Employee Details";
}

<h2>Details for @Model.Employee.FirstName</h2>
<div>
    <p class="">@Model.Employee.FirstName @Model.Employee.LastName</p>
    <p class="text-muted">@Model.Employee.Birthdate</p>
    <p class="text-secondary">@Model.Employee.Email</p>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" asp-page="./EditEmp" asp-route-id="@Model.Employee.Id">Edit Info</a>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="">@Model.Address.Street</p>
    <p class="text-muted">@Model.Address.City, @Model.Address.State @Model.Address.Zip</p>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" asp-page="./EditAdd" asp-route-id="@Model.Address.Id">Edit Address</a>
</div>
```

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
namespace RelationshipTesting.Pages.Emp
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly TestDbContext _context;

        public DetailsModel(TestDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public EmployeeAddress Address { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int id)
        {
            Employee = await _context.Employees.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e=>e.Id == id);
            Address = await _context.EmployeeAddresses
                .Where(e=>e.EmployeeId == id)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
           
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

**EditAdd.cshtml**

```
@page "{id:int}"
@model EditAddModel
@{
}
<h2>Editing Your Address</h2>

<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Address.Id" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address.Street"></label>
        <input asp-for="Address.Street" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Address.Street"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address.City"></label>
        <input asp-for="Address.City" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Address.City"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address.State"></label>
        <input asp-for="Address.State" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Address.State"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address.Zip"></label>
        <input asp-for="Address.Zip" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Address.Zip"></span>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
    <a class="text-danger" asp-page="./Index" asp-route-id="@Model.Address.EmployeeId">Cancel</a>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

**EditAdd.cshtml.cs**

```
public class EditAddModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly TestDbContext _context;

        public EditAddModel(TestDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public EmployeeAddress Address { get; set; }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int id)
        {
            Address = await _context.EmployeeAddresses.FindAsync(id);
            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            Address = await _context.EmployeeAddresses.FindAsync(id);

            _context.Update(Address);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("./Index", new {id = Address.EmployeeId});
        }
    }
```

My page to edit the employee is practically the same, but if you need it let me know and I'll drop it in here. I'm trying to work my way up to using an interface to do all this but need to master the basics and the Microsoft Docs aren't helping me too much.

### -------------------------------- UPDATE------------------------

- 

**EditEmp.cshtml.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.Attach(Employee).State = EntityState.Modified;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index", new {id = Employee.Id});
        }
```

Comment: Can you show your `OnPostAsync` for your employee edit page actually? Then it might be easier to point out what's going on. But as of now `Address = await _context.EmployeeAddresses.FindAsync(id);` followed by `_context.Update(Address);` basically just reads the entity from the DB and tries to update it again without modifying it, so that's not gonna make any changes in the DB.

Comment: @Xerillio I added the OnPost method. I know its different using the Attach part but I've refactored/played around so much on EditAdd that I can't remember if I've used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare the `OnPostAsync` methods in your two edit pages, you have the following:

```cs
// EditEmp.cshtml.cs (some lines left out for brevity)
_context.Attach(Employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


// EditAdd.cshtml.cs (some lines left out for brevity)
Address = await _context.EmployeeAddresses.FindAsync(id);
_context.Update(Address);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

In *EditEmp.cshtml.cs* you are telling Entity Framework that the contents of the `Employee` entity have been modified followed by a call to `SaveChangesAsync`. This works because you have probably bound your `Employee` property to the view.

In *EditAdd.cshtml.cs*, however, you are getting a fresh copy of the entity from the database: `_context.EmployeeAddresses.FindAsync(id)` and then telling Entity Framework to update that entity in the database as if it has been modified: `_context.Update(Address)`. But since you just fetched it from the DB there are actually no changes made in `Address`.

Instead you should do just like you are doing it in *EditEmp.cshtml.cs*:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    _context.Attach(Address).State = EntityState.Modified;

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToPage("./Index", new {id = Address.EmployeeId});
}
```

Because you have bound your `Address` property to the view via `[BindProperty]` the `Address` will contain the updated values when `OnPostAsync` is called.

Comment: I realized that I had tried this before but got the Index page doesn't exist error. I went back and realized I was not passing the EmployeeId into the page as a hidden input. Is there a way to allow that to be excluded?

Comment: @KentHub If you don't "bind" all properties of the model in the view I believe the only alternative is what Yinqiu suggests. However, with that approach you are making an additional call to the database. Perhaps that's not an issue for you performance wise but it's worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 1):

When you update Address, you did not bind the updated Address to the Post method, so you cannot update Address. You can try the following:

Modify the post method in your `EditAdd.cshtml.cs` as follows:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id,EmployeeAddress address)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        Address = await _context.EmployeeAddresses.FindAsync(id);
        Address.City = address.City;
        Address.State = address.State;
        Address.Street = address.Street;
        Address.Zip = address.Zip;
         _context.Update(Address);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToPage("./Index", new { id = Address.EmployeeId });
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: While I've seen this approach, it's not exactly what I would prefer. However, it does appear to allow only specified properties to be used, that way I don't need to provide a hidden field for EmployeeId. Is my assumption correct on that?

Comment: Yes,you only need to bind AddressId,then find the corresponding Address according to the AddressId, and then update the Address.